# Google Translate throws 'System.Net.Http.WinHttpException' Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, google-translate, google-api-dotnet-client

Using Asp.Net Core 1.1.0-preview1-001153-00 and Google C# sdk of 1.20.0.543 when I send 400 requests using the code below I run into an error ("System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established) with the HttpClient when requesting more than 400 at at time. It doesn't appear to be a quota issue as I'm seeing the backoff warning in the output.

```
List<Task<TranslationsListResponse>> requestToGoogle = model.SourceItems
    .Select(async request => await TranslateAsync(new string[] { request.SourceText }, model.TargetLanguage, model.SourceLanguage)).ToList();

TranslationsListResponse[] result = await Task.WhenAll(requestToGoogle);
```

Part of the stack trace:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteUnparsedAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at GoogleTranslate.Client.GoogleTranslateClient.<GoogleTranslateAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\myProject\src\GoogleTranslate.Client\GoogleTranslateClient.cs:line 41
```

Comment: Seems to be a threadpool issue as adding even a 1ms delay inside of the select expression increases throughput considerably.

Comment: Was that a solution to your issue? If so you should post it as an answer.